# Can not install Oracle database in Linux 7

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle12c, database-installation

I am trying to install Oracle database to Linux machine.I am getting error down below

> > > Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<

I run commands down below but it still returns error.
What should I do?

```
      [oracle@localhost ~]$ hostname
      localhost.localdomain
      [oracle@localhost ~]$ DISPLAY=localhost.localdomain:0.0; export DISPLAY 
      [oracle@localhost ~]$ xclock
      Error: Can't open display: localhost.localdomain:0.0
```

Linux Version

```
        [root@localhost oracle]# uname -a
        Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 19 
         11:24:13 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Oracle Db Version 12.2.01

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: If you want to use linux x forwarding, you should change localhost to your client host ip address. A xwindow software like as mx or xming should be installed on your client host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
# as root. Grant access to everyone to the X Server
#xhost + 
# as oracle
$export DISPLAY=:0.0
$xclock
$./runInstaller
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to install Linux with gui
2. Then check

> echo $DISPLAY

This command must output like :0